# Access the context variables stored in watson conversation using node.js

Tags: node.js, watson-conversation

I want to access the context variables saved in watson conversation JSON through an APP using node.js.

I have tried saving the whole conversation log into [cloudant](https://cloudant.com/getting-started-with-cloudant-ibm-bluemix/) and fetched it from there.

Is there a easier way to access the context variables? I am thinking of sending a http request to server to fetch the *right* variables (I dont know which variables to access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs you can store context in the browser session. This is what the conversation-simple app does.. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple
In this case the JSON context object is passed down to the browser, and passed back up again with subsequent requests.
The alternative is to store this info in a custom store such as Cloudant

Answer (score 0):

The response that one get from Conversation service is in JSON format. So you can take out any context value that are available in the "context" param of this JSON response. Following is a simple response from the Conversation service.

```
{
"intents": [],
"entities": [],
"input": {
    "text": ""
},
"output": {
    "text": ["Hello MJ! How can I help you today?"],
    "nodes_visited": ["Conversation Start"],
    "log_messages": []
},
"context": {
    "username": "MJ",
    "conversation_id": "5835fa3b-6a1c-4ec5-92f9-22844684670e",
    "system": {
        "dialog_stack": [{
            "dialog_node": "Conversation Start"
        }],
        "dialog_turn_counter": 1,
        "dialog_request_counter": 1,
        "_node_output_map": {
            "Conversation Start": [0]
        }
    }
}
```

}

You will have all your context variables in the *context* key of the response. If you check the context parameter of this response you will see the **"username": "MJ"** entry. This is a custom value that I have added to the service context. You can format this response and use it in your application as per your need.